# Why am I getting this strange error when working with findDependantRowset and Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

PHP is throwing this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAdapter() on a non-object in C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Db\Table\Row\Abstract.php on line 869
```

... when I call this code:

```
$item = $itemMapper->find(1); // Find item with id of 1     
$item->findDependentRowset("Application_Model_DbTable_SubItem");
```

I have the following other classes:

`models/DBTable/Item.php`:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Item extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
    /** Table name */
    protected $_name = 'items';
}
```

`models/DBTable/SubItem.php`:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_SubItem extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    /** Table name */
    protected $_name = 'subitems';
    protected $_referenceMap = array(
        'Item' => array(
            'columns' => 'items_id',
            'refTableClass' => 'Application_Model_DbTable_Item',
            'refColumns' => 'items_id'
        )
    );

}
```

All my models, mappers, and database tables are set up correctly, as far as I know. Accessing a model through the wrapper and `fetchAll` works fine.

My models extend `Zend_Db_Table_Row`. Why is it giving me this error?

FYI:

The line the error message cites looks like this:

```
public function findDependentRowset($dependentTable, $ruleKey = null, Zend_Db_Table_Select $select = null){

    $db = $this->_getTable()->getAdapter(); // <<<< there it is
...
```

Comment: I think find(1) returns a rowset, not a row. If you want a row, you should do: find(1)->current().

Comment: I can confirm that `find()` returns a row.

Comment: Zend Framework version 1.11.3. But, I've figured out what I did wrong. I'll post an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently, I was under the assumption that the result of `find()` returned by my mapper class was a `Zend_Db_Table_Row` object. I even tried using `instanceOf` to verify this, but I either used it incorrectly, or it lied to me.

The object returned by my mapper was simply a Model.

Calling `find()` on the `Application_Model_DbTable_Table` object returns a rowset, and `current()` works currently. After using this approach, I was able to call `findDependentRowset()` successfully.